# Reflect.set not working as intended

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

It seems unlikely that I found some kind of glaring cross-browser bug. But according to the documentations [`Reflect.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/set) is supposed to use the 4th parameter as the thisArg (for example if the set variable is a setter). The first argument is the object the value is to be set on, yet whenever I supply any object as the 4th argument, the value gets set on that instead of the target object.

```
var target = new Object;
var thisArg = new Object;

Reflect.set(target, 'variable', 52, thisArg);

target.variable == undefined
thisArg.variable == 52
```

Any explanation?

Comment: To me it looks like it is working as intended: [ECMAScript 2015 - 9.1.9 `[[SET]]( P, V, Receiver )` - Steps 4d + 5f](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver)

Comment: I don't understand alot of that, but that would be confusing. Reflect.get for example works just as described on the MDN: the target object is read from with the receiver being used as the thisArg.

Comment: Chrome might need -webkit- flag still.

Comment: As Andreas said, this is the correct behavior as defined in the spec. What other information do you need? `[[Get]]` works differently. Here the receiver is only used if the property is a getter: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first argument is the object the value is to be set on

Not exactly. The first argument is the object whose setters are invoked (including those on the object's prototype chain).

> whenever I supply any object as the 4th argument, the value gets set on that instead of the target object.

Yes. Because the property *always* gets set on the receiver. It's just that the argument is optional because it's usually the same as the target, and therefore defaults to the first argument when not supplied.

Comment: I guess the MDN page must have it wrong then, it says that the target is the object that values are set on. It **is** very confusing. You are right though, while all normal value writing gets forwarded to the receiver (if specified), it seems that getters and setters are called in the target (with the receiver as the thisArg, a complete reversal).

Comment: @JohnSmith I don't see what's reversed there. Getters and setters (that are located/inherited in the target) also do all the writing on the receiver.

Comment: I guess it's just confusing that Reflect.get reads from the target, while Reflect.set writes to the receiver. If the target of a Reflect.get call has no getters or setters, then the receiver is completely ignored, it's only optionally  specifying the thisArg in case any getters are invoked. Reflect.set on the other hand can completely ignore the target if it does not contain any setters, the receiver is the true "target".