# Why does mocha chai should not prove identity for `return this`, if I use Proxy:get in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reflection, chai, dsl

I want to write a class, that deals with undefined properties. I also want to return `this` to be able to chain methods to create a domain specific language (DSL).

I return a Proxy from the constructor, to handle undefined properties. Now when testing the instance, it does happen, that `return this` does not prove to be identical with the instance. I fear bugs resulting from this, although I can chain the methods as intended.

This is a *mocha* *chai* test to show the behaviour. Replace `o.that().should.not.equal(o);` with `o.that().should.equal(o);` in the last instruction to see how it fails.

```
require('chai').should();

describe('chai testing classes using Proxy', () => {
    it('asserts object identity, if an instance method returns this', () => {
        const o = new class NormalClass{ }
        o.that = function() { return this; }
        o.that().should.equal(o);
    });
    it('observes the same behaviour for constructors returning a dummy Proxy', () => {
        const o = new class ProxyClass{
            constructor() { return new Proxy(this, {}); }
        }
        o.that = function() { return this; }
        o.that().should.equal(o);
    });
    it('requires deep.equal on the other hand, if the Proxy handles get', () => {
        const o = new class ProxyClassPlusGet{
            constructor() {
                return new Proxy(this, {
                    get: function(target, prop) { return target[prop]; },
                });
            }
        }
        o.that = function() { return this; }
        o.that().should.deep.equal(o);
        o.that().should.not.equal(o);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation works insofar as `o.that() === o` yields `true`.

But it does not work with getters, which interferes with chai's `should`. You can reproduce this with

```js
const o = new Proxy({
    get self() { return this; },
    that() { return this; },
}, {
    get(target, prop) { return target[prop]; },
});
console.log(o.self === o);
console.log(o.that() === o);
```

Why is that?  Because your `get` trap is broken, ignoring the [receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37563495/1048572) of the property access. It will hold the proxy, `o`, but when you do `return target[prop]` then `target` will be the receiver. You can fix it by using [`Reflect.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get):

```js
const o = new Proxy({
    get self() { return this; },
    that() { return this; },
}, {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
        return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
//                                       ^^^^^^^^
    },
});
console.log(o.self === o);
console.log(o.that() === o);
```

Comment: Thank you, Bergi. It much more confusing than the magic methods in PHP.

The term `Reflect` points me to better documentation. I still have a hard time to understand the differences between target and receiver. 

So far I read the receiver is the proxy. Then calling `Reflect.get()` with the receiver would call the proxy again. Hmm, this fully confuses me. It sounds like creating a vicious circle.  Thank you so far. Sunday is scheduled to read about JS reflection. :)

Comment: @Blcknx It doesn't call the proxy again, since the property is resolved on the `target`. The `receiver` is just passed along, as the value on which the property was accessed, which should become the `this` value in getters (in the same way the `this` value is determined in method calls, independent of the object owning the method). Another example would be `const d = Object.create(o); console.log(d.self)` where the proxy is the prototype of the `d` object. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68968624/1048572) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47992070/1048572).

Comment: According to the documentation of `Reflex.get()` `target` it the template of the methods while `receiver` is the context, where the data goes. (Only in case receiver is set, which is the case).

So I don't see the property is resolved on `target`. On contrary my understanding is, that instead the proxy is temporarily updated to a full-blown object by reflection. And that is why this code works. It proves that the proxy is the proxy.

But what about the non-reflected stuff like setters. They are still delegated down to the original `this` the wrapped object.

Comment: @Blcknx Not sure what you mean by "template". `target` is the object on which the property lookup (e.g. prototype chain resolution) happens. And no, the proxy is not updated at all. Re setters: they also have separate target and receiver. If not trapped, the receiver is forwarded automatically.

Comment: For now I would say, my original code shows a sound behaviour. The proxy is not the receiver. So the test for identity fails. But it behaves like the original, so deep.equal is true. That is my hypothese for now. Today I'm gonna write some tests, to check if I am right or wrong.

Comment: Meanwhile I suspect the drawback. If I return the final receiver in my chains, I lose the magic of the proxy. So your approach may turn out right. Hope it avoids the vicious circle by not trapping into it's own get-trap again, when calling Reflect.get() with the proxy as receiver.

Comment: @Blcknx "*The proxy is not the receiver.*" - not sure what makes you think that? In `o.self`, where `o` is the proxy, the proxy *is* the receiver. And by allowing the getter to return it (instead of the proxy target object), you *don't* loose the magic of the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the concise answer given by @Bergi I add another test. It proves, that his solution shows a sound behaviour:

- It returns the identity of the *proxy* object in all cases.
- It stores the data into the underling *original* object.
- It doesn't create a vicious circle with the proxy as *receiver*.
- It works consistently with *chai expect* and *chai should*.

I still don't fully understand the proxying stuff. Doing this tests, already gives a deep insight. Kudos to @Bergi for the right solution.

```
require('chai').should();
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('general Proxy behaviour', () => {
    describe('Proxy with empty handler', () => {
        it('shows that original and proxy are two different objects' , () => {
            const original = {};
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {});
            expect(proxy).not.equal(original);
        });
        it('evaluates proxy and origianl to be deep equal' , () => {
            const original = {};
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {});
            expect(proxy).to.deep.equal(original);
        });
        it('sets and gets down to the original', () => {
            const original = {};
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {});
            proxy.x = 1;
            expect(original.x).to.equal(1);
            original.x = 2;
            expect(proxy.x).to.equal(2);
        });
        describe('consistent when accessing this', () => {
            const original = {
                getThat() { return this; },
                get that() { return this; },
            };
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, { });
            it('evaluates getters to the proxy', () => {
                expect(proxy.that).to.be.equal(proxy)
            });
            it('evaluates methods to the proxy, too', () => {
                expect(proxy.getThat()).to.be.equal(proxy)
            });
            it('chai should works like chai expect', () => {
                proxy.that.should.equal(proxy)
                proxy.getThat().should.equal(proxy)
            });
        });
    });
    describe('Proxy without reflection', () => {
        it('sets and gets down to the original like the empty handler', () => {
            const original = {};
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {
                set: function(target, prop, value) { target[prop]=value; },
                get: function(target, prop) { return target[prop]; },
            });
            proxy.x = 1;
            expect(original.x).to.equal(1);
            original.x = 2;
            expect(proxy.x).to.equal(2);
        });
        it('detects original as the target in get and set',
            () => {
                const original = {};
                let targetInSet;
                let targetInGet;
                const proxy = new Proxy(original, {
                    set: function(target, prop, value, receiver) {
                        targetInSet = target;
                        target[prop]=value;
                    },
                    get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
                        targetInGet = target;
                        expect(target).to.equal(original);
                        return target[prop];
                    },
                });
                proxy.x = 1;
                proxy.x;
                expect(targetInSet).to.equal(original);
                expect(targetInGet).to.equal(original);
        });
        it('detects proxy as the receiver in get and set',
            () => {
                const original = {};
                let receiverInSet;
                let receiverInGet;
                const proxy = new Proxy(original, {
                    set: function(target, prop, value, receiver) {
                        receiverInSet = receiver;
                        target[prop]=value;
                    },
                    get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
                        receiverInGet = receiver;
                        return target[prop];
                    },
                });
                proxy.x = 1;
                proxy.x;
                expect(receiverInSet).to.equal(proxy);
                expect(receiverInGet).to.equal(proxy);
        });
        describe('chaos when accessing this', () => {
            const original = {
                getThat() { return this; },
                get that() { return this; },
            };
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {
                get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
                    receiverInGet = receiver;
                    return target[prop];
                },
            });
            it('evaluates getters to the original', () => {
                expect(proxy.that).to.be.equal(original)
            });
            it('evaluates methods to the proxy', () => {
                expect(proxy.getThat()).to.be.equal(proxy)
            });
            it('chai should differs from chai expect', () => {
                expect(proxy.getThat()).to.be.equal(proxy)
                proxy.getThat().should.equal(original)
            });
            it('chai should evaluates to original in both cases', () => {
                proxy.getThat().should.equal(original)
                proxy.that.should.equal(original)
            });
        });
    });
    describe('Reflect in Proxy without the receiver being set', () => {
        it('sets and gets down to the original like the empty handler', () => {
            const original = {};
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {
                get: function(target, prop) {
                    return Reflect.get(target, prop);
                },
                set: function(target, prop, value) {
                    Reflect.set(target, prop, value);
                },
            });
            proxy.x = 1;
            expect(original.x).to.equal(1);
            original.x = 2;
            expect(proxy.x).to.equal(2);
        });
        describe('chaos when accessing this', () => {
            const original = {
                getThat() { return this; },
                get that() { return this; },
            };
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {
                get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
                    return Reflect.get(target, prop);
                },
            });
            it('evaluates getters to the original', () => {
                expect(proxy.that).to.be.equal(original)
            });
            it('evaluates methods to the proxy', () => {
                expect(proxy.getThat()).to.be.equal(proxy)
            });
            it('chai should differs from chai expect', () => {
                expect(proxy.getThat()).to.be.equal(proxy)
                proxy.getThat().should.equal(original)
            });
            it('chai should evaluates to original in both cases', () => {
                proxy.getThat().should.equal(original)
                proxy.that.should.equal(original)
            });
        });
    });

    describe('Reflect in Proxy with the receiver being set to original', () => {
        it('sets and gets down to the original like the empty handler', () => {
            const original = {};
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {
                get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
                    return Reflect.get(target, prop, target);
                },
                set: function(target, prop, value, receiver) {
                    Reflect.set(target, prop, value, target);
                },
            });
            proxy.x = 1;
            expect(original.x).to.equal(1);
            original.x = 2;
            expect(proxy.x).to.equal(2);
        });
        describe('chaos when accessing this', () => {
            const original = {
                getThat() { return this; },
                get that() { return this; },
            };
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {
                get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
                    return Reflect.get(target, prop, target);
                },
            });
            it('evaluates getters to the original', () => {
                expect(proxy.that).to.be.equal(original)
            });
            it('evaluates methods to the proxy', () => {
                expect(proxy.getThat()).to.be.equal(proxy)
            });
            it('chai should differs from chai expect', () => {
                expect(proxy.getThat()).to.be.equal(proxy)
                proxy.getThat().should.equal(original)
            });
            it('chai should evaluates to original in both cases', () => {
                proxy.getThat().should.equal(original)
                proxy.that.should.equal(original)
            });
        });
    });
    describe('Reflect in Proxy with the receiver being set to proxy', () => {
        it('sets and gets down to the original like the empty handler', () => {
            const original = {};
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {
                get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
                    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
                },
                set: function(target, prop, value, receiver) {
                    Reflect.set(target, prop, value, receiver);
                },
            });
            proxy.x = 1;
            expect(original.x).to.equal(1);
            original.x = 2;
            expect(proxy.x).to.equal(2);
        });
        it('does not cause a vicious circle in the proxy', () => {
            const original = {};
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {
                get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
                    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
                },
                set: function(target, prop, value, receiver) {
                    Reflect.set(target, prop, value, receiver);
                },
            });
            proxy.x = 1;
            expect(proxy.x).to.equal(1);
        });
        describe('consistent when accessing this', () => {
            const original = {
                getThat() { return this; },
                get that() { return this; },
            };
            const proxy = new Proxy(original, {
                get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
                    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
                },
            });
            it('evaluates getters to the proxy', () => {
                expect(proxy.that).to.be.equal(proxy)
            });
            it('evaluates methods to the proxy, too', () => {
                expect(proxy.getThat()).to.be.equal(proxy)
            });
            it('chai should works like chai expect', () => {
                proxy.that.should.equal(proxy)
                proxy.getThat().should.equal(proxy)
            });
        });
    });
});
```